# SwiftUI: Laggy NavigationBar Transition

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-navigationview

I am building an iPad app and occurred this weird laggy transition when I use a NavigationBar and a ScrollView. You can see it [here](https://youtu.be/PYoEmGgf6fA) (I don't know if there is another way to share videos).

My code looks like this:

```
NavigationView {
   ZStack {
      BackgroundView()
      GridView() 
   }
   .navigationTitle("HUB")         
   .toolbar{
      ...
   }
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

BackgroundView:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("background_light")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

GridView:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: homeViewModel.layout, spacing: 20, content: {
        ForEach(homeViewModel.itemButtons, id: \.self) { item in
            Button()
            ...
        }         
    }
}
```

Now I wonder whether it is a SwiftUI bug or I did something wrong and I hope you can help me.

Thank you and greetings from Germany.

EDIT: changed `.navigationBarTitle()` to `.navigationTitle()`

Comment: `navigationBarTitle` is being [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:)-6p1k7). You shouldn't use any of the `navigationBar` methods. use `.toolbar` and/or `.navigationTitle`

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for the hint. I changed it to `.navigationTitle` and it was still laggy. I tried using the `.toolbar` but it didn't fix the lag. Any other ideas?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I added further explanation for the views I'm using. Do you need more to reproduce the troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and my colleague suggested to add a padding on scroll view greater than 0. Adding 1pt padding fixed it for me. Looks like a SwiftUI bug which is not fixed for more than a year.